# Can a NFL player play for two different NFL teams in the same post season?

Tags: rules, nfl, postseason

Let's say Julio Jones got released right after the 2022 playoff game between the Tennessee Titans and the Cincinnati Bengals. Would Julio Jones be able to go play for the Kansas City Chiefs one week later in the AFC championship game in the same post season?

Comment: Related to, and perhaps duplicate of: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20822/can-a-team-sign-an-nfl-player-during-the-playoffs ?

Answer (score 3):

It was possible only for the 2020 season, due to special rules the NFL adopted due to COVID-19.

The Green Bay Packers actually had 2 players that year who could have played for 2 different teams in the postseason.

Offensive lineman Jared Veldheer played for the Colts in the wild-card game against the Bills. Then the Packers signed him off the Colts practice squad before they played the Rams in the divisional round.

A [CBS article](https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/jared-veldheer-to-make-nfl-history-by-playing-for-two-teams-in-the-same-playoffs-after-signing-with-packers/) explains that situation:

> offensive lineman Jared Veldheer is on the verge of pulling off something that has never been done in league history: play for two different playoff teams in the same postseason.
>
> After spending the bulk of the 2020 regular season without a team, Veldheer signed on with the Indianapolis Colts practice squad in late December. He was then called up in time for Indy's wild-card matchup with the Buffalo Bills, a game which the Colts ended up losing, 27-24, on Saturday. Under normal circumstances, Veldheer's 2020 season would come to a close in lockstep with Indianapolis. However, these are not normal times.
>
> Because Veldheer was on the Colts practice squad and not the active roster, and was simply elevated to the gameday roster through the NFL's special protocols to give teams flexibility during the COVID-19 pandemic, he reverted back to the practice unit right as the game ended. That tweak in the rules for this season opened the door for the Green Bay Packers to sign him, which they did on Monday, according to Adam Schefter of ESPN.
>
> Had Veldheer been on the active roster, this wouldn't have been possible as those players remain under contract with their respective team and cannot sign elsewhere -- in most cases -- until the free agency window opens with the new league year in the spring. The practice squad, however, freed him up to do continue his search for a Super Bowl.

According to [Adam Schefter](https://twitter.com/AdamSchefter/status/1348762060499390464), those special rules only applied to the 2020 season.

Veldheer ended up not playing for the Packers in the playoffs, because he was placed on the [reserve/COVID-19 list](https://www.packers.com/news/packers-placed-t-jared-veldheer-on-the-reserve-covid-19-list) prior to their divisional playoff game against the Rams.

There was also Tramon Williams, who played for the Ravens in the divisional round against the Bills. Then the Ravens waived him, and he was signed by the Packers before their NFC Championship Game against the Bucs.

A [Sporting News article](https://www.sportingnews.com/us/nfl/news/tramon-williams-packers-ravens-2021-playoffs/4pfez3zehmhpzp5juo3w0bd6) explains Williams' situation, which was different from Veldheer's:

> Williams, who previously spent 10 years playing for the Packers from 2007-2014 and 2018-19, gets a chance at this unprecedented opportunity for two reasons. First, the Ravens waived Williams after their season-ending loss, something teams usually wait until the conclusion of the postseason to do. And second, the 2020 season's COVID-19 rules allow for more practice squad flexibility, which allowed Williams to come on board.
>
> The possibility of Williams playing for the Packers in the NFC Championship was set into motion by the Ravens' unusual move after their season-ending loss to Buffalo on Jan. 16. Normally, teams wait to waive veteran players until after the Super Bowl.
>
> Once Williams cleared waivers, the Packers could add him to their practice squad. In a regular season, a veteran such as Williams couldn't be placed on a practice squad, but COVID-19 rules allow for up to four veterans on the 16-man practice squad.
>
> COVID-19 rules then allowed for Williams to be placed on the active roster. Practice squad players can be promoted as COVID-19 replacements. Green Bay offensive lineman Jared Veldheer, who shaped up to make this exact history after suiting up for the Colts in a wild card game, is on the COVID-19/reserve list. Williams has been promoted in part to take Veldheer's expected place on the active roster.

So Williams could have played against the Bucs, but he ended up not playing a snap in that game, which the Packers lost.